# Problem connecting a third monitor via the USB port of the Dell D6000 dock in Ubuntu 20.04. Only recognizes audio input

Tags: 20.04, usb, dock, displayport, displaylink

I have a Dell dock and I can't connect a third monitor via the Dell dock to the USB port on the notebook (Dell too) with Ubuntu 20.04, but curiously it only recognizes the monitor as an audio input and not as a screen input.

I've tried everything, installing drivers, etc. On Windows it was very easy to use the dock with the third monitor.

Below are the notebook system settings:

[image]

Audio-only recognition:

[image]